# How do you use the Solr DIH to select XML based on descriptive values?

Tags: solr, solr4

The XML has some descriptive fields and I would like to use them to select specific fields. Is there a way to get the data import handler to pick only "Text Block A" and "Text Block B" using "code=34089-3" as a key? The code field has no data but it is unique to the type of information I want to pick. When I use xpath="/document/component/section/text/paragraph" I end up with text blocks A, B, C and D. Ideally I would like to be able to pick only text block A. Is this even possible?

```
<component>
  <section>
     <id root="f915965e-fe3b-44eb-a2ed-c11f807e7f23"/>
     <code code="34089-3"/>
     <title>Title A</title>
     <text>
       <paragraph>Text Block A</paragraph>
       <paragraph>Text Block B</paragraph>
     </text>
   </section>
</component>
<component>
  <section>
     <id root="80b7e2f1-f49f-4309-a340-210536705d4a"/>
     <code code="34090-1"/>
     <title>Title B</title>
     <text>
       <paragraph>Text Block C</paragraph>
       <paragraph>Text Block D</paragraph>
     </text>
   </section>
</component>


<entity 
name="IUPAC" 
processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
forEach="/document"
url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}">

     <field column="chemical_name" xpath="/document/component/section/code[@code='34089-3']/access below values???" />

</entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
/document/component/section[code/@code='34089-3']/text/paragraph
```

Comment: Thanks...but that didn't work. I think this might be a limitation of the xpath implementation in solr. I'm trying understand how to apply the "xsl" option in this situation, but have yet to be successful.

Comment: What about processing all sections and just tell Solr to skip those where code is not correct? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-SpecialCommandsfortheDataImportHandler with some transformer?